# Windows 10 start menu, any way to search for folder names like Win7

Tags: windows, search, start

I miss how win7 used to allow you to search out and manage the start menu.  For me I have a bunch of folders where the installer named them in a hierarchical way.  Say Red-Gate > SQL compare, or Cherry Audio > MS20.

I would love to be able to type "red" or "cherry" into the search and see all child apps/folders.  I don't always remember the program names explicitly, and it would be great to see all of my red-gate programs by typing red.  I would prefer not to have to make weird shortcuts to handle this.  Any idea how this can be done?  I tried alternative shells and they don't work that way either.

Comment: When you open Search, did you select Documents.  My Windows 10 search seems to work. Are you searching in Indexed Locations?

Comment: As John states, is the folder location fully indexed? Rebuild the Index: https://www.alphr.com/how-to-solve-windows-search-issues-index-rebuild/ , and include filenames.

Comment: Thanks, I have done so already.  It is not finding the parent folders but only contents.  Thank you!